# Is there any possibility to pass data from browser to a Qt WebAssembly app - maybe as an environment variable?

Tags: qt, webassembly

I have a client application written in Qt that runs with WebAssembly in a web browser. Now I want to pass the Server URL as an environment variable to the application (I don't want to recompile the app for each different server the client connects to).

My goal is to access the qt app with something like
    http://server1.myclient.io 
and some javascript sets the environment variable 
    SERVER_URL=wss://server1.foo.org

This allows me to connect to different servers with the same binary but different subdomains.

Answer (score 4):

If the purpose is to simply get the server address, it is possible to access it in the C++ code of your Qt application.

```
#include <emscripten/val.h>
...
emscripten::val location = emscripten::val::global("location");
auto host = location["hostname"].as<std::string>();
auto port = location["port"].as<std::string>();
```

This will basically give you access to the JavaScript window.location object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still relevant for you, but I was looking for an solution for the exact same problem and found this thread in the official Qt forums:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/112228/qt-webasssembly-pass-url-parameter-to-qml/4

> There is a change not yet integrated that does just this:
>
> https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/248624
>
> Its a small change to qtloader.js so you don't even need to recompile. as most  of the work is already in Emscripten. You can access the arguments the normal way QCoreApplication::arguments()
>
> So a url such as this:
> http://192.168.1.106:6931/wasm-args.html?arguments=yes&argument2=no
>
> Will receive the arguments like this:
> ("./this.program", "arguments=yes", "argument2=no")*

For myself, I am still looking for an elegant solution to not show the arguments in the address

Answer (score 0):

@Karmo's answer helped me tremendously. However, I found that `window.location.href` to be what I really needed:

```cpp
#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
#include <emscripten/val.h>
#include <emscripten.h>
#endif

// ...

QUrl App::href() const {
#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
    emscripten::val location = emscripten::val::global("location");
    return QUrl(QString::fromStdString(location["href"].as<std::string>()));
#else
    return QUrl();
#endif
}
```